# How does one move python and other types of files from one GCP notebook instance to another?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have a Vertex AI notebook that contains a lot of python and jupyter notebook as well as pickled data files in it.  I need to move these files to another notebook.  There isn't a lot of documentation on google's help center.

Has someone had to do this yet?  I'm new to GCP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try these steps in this [article](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/user-managed/migrate). It says you can copy your files to a [Google Cloud Storage Bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) then move it to a new notebook by using gsutil tool.

In your notebook's terminal run this code to copy an object to your Google Cloud storage bucket:

```
gsutil cp -R /home/jupyter/* gs://BUCKET_NAMEPATH
```

Then open a new terminal to the target notebook and run this command to copy the directory to the notebook:

```
gsutil cp gs://BUCKET_NAMEPATH* /home/jupyter/
```

Just change the `BUCKET_NAMEPATH` to the name of your cloud storage bucket.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that both notebooks are on the same GC project and that you have the same permissions on both, ok?

There are many ways to do that... Listing some here:

1. The hardest to execute, but the simplest by concept: You can download everything for your computer/workstation from the original notebook instance, then go to the second notebook instance and upload everything
2. You can use [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/), the object storage service to be used as the medium for the files movement. To do that you need to (1) [create a storage bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets), (2) then using your notebook instance terminal, [copy the data from the instance to the bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects), (3) and finally use the console on the target notebook instance and [copy the data from the bucket to the instance](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects)