# How to recover notebook runtime in unhealthy state

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-colab-enterprise

A Runtime has been in "Unhealthy" state for ~12 hours and has not recovered.

I need to access it again because it has storage data I need, but there does not seem to be any way to recover an "Unhealthy" runtime (not through the UI, neither through API)

Answer (score 0):

A Runtime consists of 2 disks: boot disk and data disk. The runtime is a hidden VM in User Project, unfortunately the visibility is hidden so access is not possible (Currently is not possible to take an snapshot of disks or SSH into it). I have opened a FR to handle this case. We have a logs section that can shed some light of what may have been the issue.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation about what the runtime actually is under the hood. As for what the issue was: the runtime went into a bad state after I ran a program that used up all RAM

Comment: Thanks @FreshLaptop we are rolling out a change in prod for better memory management where we don't allow anymore for the main container to use up all Host memory. I tested few scenarios, just curious if you can share steps to reproduce to make sure new mechanism covers your situation. (Production rollout should be completed by next week)

Comment: Sorry, I don't exactly remember what the code was. It was a snippet of code to test something in the notebook, I made a mistake in slicing an array

Answer (score -1):

Are you able to access the terminal even in an unhealthy state? if yes you can try copying the files through terminal to a bucket with this command:

`gsutil cp -R /content/\* gs://BucketName`

The content is default location when you open the directory of the runtime, you can change it to any directory desired.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73030233/19378826

Comment: I am unable to access the terminal. I ended up deleting the runtime and creating another one.